# Generic Text Converter

Tags: batch-file

I want to make a generic batch script which will read a schema file which will contain the various width's/column length's of the fixed width flat file source and finally create a target csv file based on the column length.

Example:

Schema.txt

```
COL1,5
COL2,2
COL3,4
COL4,3
COL5,6
```

So the above schema.txt file contains the column list.It also contains the width of each field. Our source will always be a fixed width flat file. Our objective will be to convert it into csv.

Source1.txt

```
11111223333444555555
11111223333444555555
```

Target1.txt

```
11111,22,3333,444,555555
11111,22,3333,444,555555
```

Source2.txt

```
11111  333344466666
11111223333   66666
```

Target2.txt

```
11111,,3333,444,66666
11111,22,333,,66666
```

so it should be able to handle space and blanks as well, as we saw in 2nd Source file.
The schema should be a dynamic file where if we provide the structure the bat file will create a csv exactly like the structure from the source.The final target file should have the header taken from the schema file.
Please help.

My present code is given below:

```
echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo a,b,c    final.txt
rem replace the €€€ string with any unused one
set "fooString=€€€" 
for /f "tokens=1 delims=;" %%i in (source.txt) do (
  set "x=%%i"
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (config.txt) do (
    call SET "VARraw=!x:~%%a,%%b!%fooString%"
    rem replaced with respect to the OP's comment: for %%p in (!VARraw!) do (
    for /F "tokens=*" %%p in ("!VARraw!") do (
      set "rav=%%p"
      set "var=!rav:%fooString%=!"
      echo/|set /p "=!var!,"
    )         final.txt
  )
)
```

Present config.txt contains

```
0,9
9,3
12,11
23,7
30,1
```

But i want to modify it.Want to keep only the Field name and the width. Not the starting position and the width.

Problem with existing code is that it prints the result in one single line but i want the \n after the end of each line.

Comment: What have you tried so far? please share your code! we are not going to do your work for you, we are here to help you with specific programming problems you encounter; take a look also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)...

Comment: @aschipfl I love how this starts with "I want to make" and after that just tells what he wants us to make.

Comment: @DennisvanGils: _"I want that you make a generic batch script for me that..."_ Yes, I think this would be a more realistic description of this problem. **`;-)`**

Comment: 'For /f` can read your file, `set` can assign the contents to variables. `Set` can also extract substrings using previous variables, `echo` can echo it out. This will be ugly as it's the wrong language for doing this.

Comment: @aschipfl I have edited my question. Please ask me if you need anything else. Thanks

Comment: @DennisvanGils,. Thank you for your comments. It was really constructive ;-)

Comment: @Aacini. Thank you for your comments. It was really constructive ;-)

Comment: @Noodles What do you suggest then? I dont have much knowledge about VBScript, Powershell etc.

Comment: See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326548. Then you just read the file by record/field name.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Load the schema
set /A numCol=0, maxSpc=0
set "header="
set "spaces="
for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in (Schema.txt) do (
   set /A numCol+=1
   set "header=!header!,%%a"
   set "col[!numCol!]=%%b"
   if %%b gtr !maxSpc! (
      set /A spc=%%b-maxSpc, maxSpc=%%b
      for /L %%i in (1,1,!spc!) do set "spaces=!spaces! "
   )
)

rem Process the input file
echo %header:~1%
for /F "delims=" %%a in (%1) do (
   set "in=%%a"
   set "start=0"
   set "out="
   for /L %%i in (1,1,%numCol%) do for /F "tokens=1,2" %%j in ("!start! !col[%%i]!") do (
      set "col=!in:~%%j,%%k!"
      if "!col!" equ "!spaces:~0,%%k!" set "col="
      set "out=!out!,!col!"
      set /A start+=%%k
   )
   echo !out:~1!
)
```

Output of example session:

```
C:\> type Schema.txt
COL1,5
COL2,2
COL3,4
COL4,3
COL5,6

C:\> type Source1.txt
11111223333444555555
11111223333444555555

C:\> test Source1.txt
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
11111,22,3333,444,555555
11111,22,3333,444,555555

C:\> type Source2.txt
11111  333344466666
11111223333   66666

C:\> test Source2.txt
COL1,COL2,COL3,COL4,COL5
11111,,3333,444,66666
11111,22,3333,,66666
```

Comment: What happened? Isn't this solution useful?

Comment: your solution was perfect. I could never have written such a mature code , at least not with the present scripting knowledge i have in dos. Just two things i want to ask:   1. If i use this code for a large file with around 0.1 million records, it is taking very long to build the final output. Is it the limitation of dos ? 2. If possible please walk me a bit through your code as i want to learn.. not blindly copy paste... thanks again for helping me.

Comment: @Aschipfl ... your code works like a charm as well. It takes a bit long when i try to process 0.1 million records. It has something to do with limitations of DOS ? Also if possible can you please walk me through a bit with your code , as i want to learn not simply copy paste.. Thanks Again for helping me.

Comment: @Sumit, please take a look at this help page: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

The following script (let us call it `convert.bat`) converts a text file given via command line argument into a CSV file according to your requirements. You may provide the result file as a second argument; if omitted, the output is displayed at the console. The default schema file `Schema.txt` can be changed if a third argument is specified: (so use like: `convert.bat source.txt [target.txt [schema.txt]]`)

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Remove leading blanks of every field if this value is non-empty:
set "DELBLANKS=REMOVE"

rem Specify source file as first command line argument:
set "SOURCE=%~1"
rem Specify target file as second argument (optionally):
set "TARGET=%~2"
rem Provide scheme file as third argument (default is "Schema.txt"):
set "SCHEME=%~3"

rem Check the given command line arguments:
if not defined SOURCE >&2 echo ERROR:  no source file given! & exit /B 1
if not defined TARGET set "TARGET=con"
if not defined SCHEME set "SCHEME=%~dp0Schema.txt"

rem Read scheme file and build header:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "HEADER="
set /A POSITION=0
set /A COLUMN=0
for /F "usebackq tokens=1,2 delims=," %%I in ("!SCHEME!") do (
    set /A COLUMN+=1
    set "HEADER=!HEADER!,%%I"
    if not "%%J"=="" (
        set "WIDTH=%%J"
        set /A WIDTH[!COLUMN!]+=WIDTH
        set /A POSITION[!COLUMN!]=POSITION
        set /A POSITION+=WIDTH
    )
)

rem Convert source file into CSV format and store to target file:
> "!TARGET!" (
    echo(!HEADER:~1!
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("!SOURCE!") do (
        setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "LINE=!LINE:,=;!"
        set "CSV="
        for /L %%C in (1,1,%COLUMN%) do (
            for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=," %%P in ("!POSITION[%%C]!,!WIDTH[%%C]!") do (
                if defined DELBLANKS (
                    for /F tokens^=*^ eol^= %%S in ("!LINE:~%%P,%%Q!,") do (
                        for /F "delims=" %%T in (""!CSV!"") do (
                            endlocal
                            set "CSV=%%~T%%S"
                            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
                            set "LINE=!LINE:,=;!"
                        )
                    )
                ) else (
                    set "CSV=!CSV!!LINE:~%%P,%%Q!,"
                )
            )
        )
        if defined CSV echo(!CSV:~,-1!
        endlocal
        endlocal
    )
)
endlocal

endlocal
exit /B
```

The headers in the schema file should not contain any exclamation marks `!`.
Any commas `,` in the source file will be replaced by semicolons `;`.