# Add delimiter to txt file from batch script in Windows

Tags: database, csv, batch-file, delimiter

I have a text.txt file that is filled with data that is not separated by a delimiter. I need to add a delimiter based on columns in the text file.

The data currently looks like

```
00067800000000000000000000N00006N 00000125463150050000012546315012
00067800000000000000000000N00006N 00000125463150810000012546315098
```

and I need to be add a delimiter such as "," at specific columns in the text so it comes out looking like.

```
000678,0000000,000000,0000000,N,00006,N, ,00000,12546315005,00000,12546,315012
000678,0000000,000000,0000000,N,00006,N, ,00000,12546315081,00000,12546,315098
```

I would like to create a batch file that goes through and adds the delimiter , at each column I need it for every line in the file.

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [2-minute tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour). 
Moreover, open [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and read at least _What topics can I ask about here_? 
Then you know what we expect from questioners: showing us the code on 
where you stuck solving the task by yourself and explaining why you fail to complete the task. Sorry, but Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service. However, you could start here: [Variables: extract part of a variable (substring)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html).

Comment: Related: [Generic Text Converter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35930679)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=U:\destdir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q39666479.txt"
SET "outfile=%destdir%\outfile.txt"

:: set delimiter and read column-sizes from supplied command-line
SET "delimiter=,"
CALL :colsize %*

(
FOR /f "usebackqdelims=" %%a IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 SET "line=%%a"
 CALL :report
)
)>"%outfile%"

GOTO :EOF

:colsize
SET "magic="
:: offset position
SET /a size=0
:colsizelp
IF DEFINED magic (
 SET "magic=%magic%%delimiter%`line:~%size%,%1`"
) ELSE (
 SET "magic=`line:~%size%,%1`"
)
SET /a size +=%1
SHIFT
IF "%1" neq "" GOTO colsizelp
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET "magic=!magic:`=%%!"
endlocal&SET "magic=set "line=%magic%""
GOTO :eof

:report
CALL %magic%
ECHO %line%
GOTO :eof
```

You would need to change the settings of `sourcedir`, `filename1` and `destdir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q39666479.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Produces the file defined as %outfile%

Run as *thisbatchname* 6,7,6,7,1,5,1,1,5,11,5,5,6

to produce the above result. Each number is simply the column-width.

Essentially, build the string `magic` as appropriate substring commands strung together to assemble the output line as required. With each line from the file, execute the `magic` command and `echo` the result.

Comment: When I run this I get a Missing operand. comment in cmd. The output file is filled with Echo is off.

Comment: Can't tell without your providing more info. Did you try retyping the file, or did you copy-and-paste? What software did you use to build the batch file? Sometimes NOTEPAD tries to reformat files - try using Notepad+ or Editplus. Changing `@echo off` to `@echo on` will reproduce a listing of the routine as it executes. This may be useful in debugging - especially the `missing operand` issue.

Comment: This is what shows up in the cmd. I copy and pasted, and I use Notepad++
http://pastebin.com/fvUuf6ju

Turning on echo also filled the output.txt with more info.
http://pastebin.com/P2fNJFE9

Comment: My co-worker just help me realize I was running the batch file wrong. So it worked mostly. Until it ran into a & in the data. That broke it pretty good.

Comment: Yes, it will have problems with certain symbols. Batch is not the best approach to this problem. I'd suggest you try SED instead if processsing symbols like `<>%&|` (and no doubt others) is envisaged. With your sample as representative, it works fine.

Comment: I could definitely take a different approach to it. I've never heard for SED before though. So going in there completely blind.

Comment: I didn't realize originally that there was an & in it. There are roughly 57,000 Lines of Data I got dumped on my desk yesterday, but your help has been very appreciated! Thank you so much.